# Codeigniter pagination only showing last page selected

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My url is: http://[::1]/cashback/index.php/home/brand_offers/3

in which 3 denotes the brand id

My controller:

```
public function brand_offers($id=null) //getting id of brand from view all offers link in pages
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config=['base_url'=> base_url('index.php/home/brand_offers'.$id),'per_page'=>2,'total_rows'=>$this->home_offers->total_rows($id)];
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $brand_offers=$this->home_offers->brand_offers($id,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
    $brand_desc=$this->home_offers->brand_desc($id);
    $this->load->view('brand_offers',['offers'=>$brand_offers,'desc'=>$brand_desc]);
}
```

My Model:

```
public function brand_offers($id,$limit,$offset)// get offers according to brand id
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->select('offers.id as oid,offers.offer_type,offers.discount,offers.coupon_code,offers.offer_title,offers.offer_url,offers.offer_desc,brands.brand_logo,brands.bid,brands.brand_desc,brands.brand_banner,brands.brand_url')
            ->from('offers')
            ->join('brands','offers.brand_id=brands.bid')
            ->where('offers.status','0')
            ->where('brands.brand_status','0')
            ->where('offers.brand_id',$id)
            ->order_by('offers.id','DESC')
            ->limit($limit,$offset);
    $q=$this->db->get();
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $q->result();
}
```

And in view i am printing the pagination using

```
$this->pagination->create_links()
```

I am getting the links but the last link is selected automatically and if i select the previous link it still show last page selected and last page data

Comment: Just a tip I noticed you have ip in url you should set your base url on config.php because some links will not work. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';`

Comment: That's because you didn't specify the uri_segment in your pagination config, since you're accepting a variable your ``uri_segment`` should be set to 4